# NAS Subfolder Access Issue (Windows 10 Home)

Tags: networking, windows-10, permissions, nas, sharing

I have Seagate Personal Cloud NAS, and I am able to access (most) of it by logging in through Windows Explorer as my PC is on the same home network as NAS. I am also able to access all folders via Seagate's web interface and iOS app, i.e. folders are not corrupted, totally inaccessible, etc. I can also access it through WebDAV and a dedicated address (.../dav/...)

I am not able to access one folder though through Windows Explorer, and because of that I'm unable to do automated backups from Windows. Basic error in the Explorer is:

> Windows cannot access\192.168.1.116\Public\Backup\Documents. Contact your administrator...

Invoking folder properties, then Security tab will bring up another notification:

> The permissions on Documents are incorrectly ordered, which may cause
>   some entries to be ineffective.

and there is an `OK` button.

In the list of user names in the Security tab I can see the username I use to log in to this drive, with all permissions set to Full Control. If I try to change any of the permissions I will get:

> The permissions on Documents are incorrectly ordered,...

warning with options to click `Reorder` or `Cancel`. Any further action will be wrapped up with:

> An error occurred while applying security information to... Failed to
>   enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied.

Advanced Security settings for this folder show the correct ownership and if I try to change anything (child object permissions, etc.) I will receive the same errors.

Trying `takeown` and `icacls` will also result in Access is denied.

So I'm not sure what else I can do to try and set the permissions right. I guess another computer/backup program set something off but I don't know how to convince NAS' local OS/file system that I logged in properly and can access the folder. Or how to change the permissions for it. To complicate the things even more, I believe this NAS is running some sort of *NIX, and I'm accessing it from Windows.

Any ideas on what I can do? File services I have enabled on the NAS are: SMB, FTP, SFTP, and WebDAV. Seagate's own Seagate Access is also on.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same user since firmware upgrade this year.  I am looking at enabling this service in the device manager of the Personal Cloud itself.

WebDAV
" Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning. Enable WebDAV to allow remote web servers to access and manage one or more shares."

To my understanding, a security patch in the firmware upgrade closed the availability to edit files remotely.

From:  https://webdrive.com/what-is-a-webdav-client/

**Overview of WebDAV Protocol**

Many cloud-based collaboration services use WebDAV protocol, or their own adaptations to enable their collaborative features. WebDAV is short for Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning and was developed by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) in the 2007 RFC 4918.

The key advantage of WebDAV vs. FTP and other file transfer protocols is the inclusion of properties such as author and modification time of a document in its metadata. This facilitates the WebDAV locking feature, sometimes referred to as DAV locking.

DAV Locking

The locking feature blocks the write permission for everyone but the person currently editing a file. This feature prevents overwrite conflicts, and it allows a resource to be occupied by one user only at a time. One user cannot overwrite another user’s edits; the person who opened the document first has the edit rights. Furthermore, WebDAV can display who last edited a file, which is very useful for administrators and support teams.

Benefits of using WebDAV Clients

So what is a WebDAV Client? Much like FTP clients, WebDAV clients connect users to a web server so they can upload and download files. WebDAV clients also enable users to edit and collaborate on files on a WebDAV server.

WebDAV is extremely beneficial in a corporate setting, particularly with corporate Sharepoint servers or other WebDAV-based corporate servers. This is because it allows for a frictionless transition from individual to collaborative work- multiple users can edit the same file remotely without worry of overwriting one another.

Some cloud services have proprietary protocols that are extensions to WebDAV, so products like WebDrive support standard WebDAV, as well as the specific cloud services that use proprietary protocols. This lets the user access corporate and cloud servers through a single interface. And since WebDrive maps a network drive letter, users can access all of these services through the convenience of Windows Explorer or Mac Finder. Files are also accessible through the applications that users rely on every day.

Popular Services that use WebDAV

Services such as SharePoint, SharePoint Online, MyDocsOnline, and Synology all use WebDAV. A WebDAV client, like WebDrive, lets you access your remote storage as though it were right on your desktop. With WebDrive, you can easily map a network drive to your remote storage service and connect via WebDAV. Then, assign a drive letter (W, for example) to your storage, so you can simply click and access all of your files from the familiar interface of your Mac Finder or Windows Explorer.